# Calculated Column in a Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm newbie to ASP.Net

I have three dropdowns from 1-5 in the GridView

And a textbox which is made  **disabled=true** using css.

I need to calculate the Total based on the selection on the three dropdowns.

This calculation of total has to be dynamic.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion Add a button also into the grid so that you can display the sum of three dropdownlist's value in the textbox on that button click.

And then try this code in your gridview's rowcommand function

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList2");
    DropDownList ddl3 = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList3");

    TextBox txt = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("TextBox1");

    txt.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(ddl2.SelectedItem.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(ddl2.SelectedItem.Text)).ToString();

}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to write javascript function and assign in to each drop down 'onchange' event passing this dropdown object:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="dropdownChanged(this)">
```

In js function you can calculate sum of selected values and save it to textbox. This way you avoid doing postback and it works very quick.

Best way to do it in js is to use jquery. Check jquery documentation to see how to code particular steps:

1. Get  element that is closest to dropdown object passed as parameter (this). This will give you row object.
2. Foreach drop down that you want to calculate sum from add dropdown's value to variable.
   If those 3 dropdowns are the only dropdowns in the row you can use getElementsByTagName("select") on row object to get array and then calculate sum in 'for' loop. If you have more drop downs, use jquery to get desired dropdowns by part of id.
3. Use jquery to get target text box inside row (by part of id or by tag type) and assign calculated value to it's 'value' property.